# What does the notation $ 1_{\{x \geq 0\}}(x)$ mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I'm taking a course on statistics and I'm not a math student so I'm not familiar with the following notation for a pdf:

$$f_X(x) =c.e^{-\lambda x}1_{\{x \geq 0\}}(x)$$

I don't get what:

$$ 1_{\{x \geq 0\}}(x)$$

means?

Comment: It's an indicator function.

Comment: It equals one when the condition is satisfied, zero otherwise.

Comment: It is a faulty use of the notation stipulating that $\mathbf 1_A$ is the function such that $\mathbf 1_A(x)=1$ if $x$ is in $A$ and $\mathbf 1_A(x)=0$ otherwise. "Faulty" because of the conflict between the two occurences of the symbol $x$. A rigorous notation would be $$f_X(x) =ce^{-\lambda x}\mathbf 1_{x \geq 0}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write either
$$
1_{x\ge 0}
$$
or
$$
1_{[0,\infty)} (x).
$$
Either way, it's equal to $1$ when $x\ge 0$ and to $0$ when $x<0$.